# Jenkins job to check if the syntax of any given YAML file is correct

Tags: syntax, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to build a Jenkins Job to check if the syntax of any given YAML file is correct for project requirement. Is this possible?

The only validators I find are online web portals based where you copy paste your code and check for the syntax. Is this possible to achieve via Jenkins job job.??

Comment: I don't know much about Jenkins, but one command-line tool that you can use to check YAML syntax would be [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3#validate-documents).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.